# Find "seasonality" in a categorical time series in python

Tags: time-series, markov-hidden-model

I have the following sequence:

```
states_list = ['H', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'A', 'S', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'S', 'H', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Is there a way to find "seasonality" on this time series ?

By "seasonality" I mean, if there is a specific a specific sub-sequence of letters popping up every "n" letters

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a time-series problem, since there is no observable time series event, unless you have some sort of stochastic process that generates letters. If not, You just have a list of repeating characters. However, This DOES look like a repeating sequence problem, similar to how you would identify DNA sequences.

Comment: @RalphWinters you could look at it from a DNA sequence perspective as well, indeed

Answer (score 1):

To do that you can use seasonal_decompose (https://machinelearningmastery.com/decompose-time-series-data-trend-seasonality/) .Before using it you will need to take care of Nan.After that you can use Dickey — Fuller test to check for stationary.You can easiy transform your data to fit to this example.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the series are categorical. How would you transform them ?

Comment: My idea was to use Label Encoding  to transfer the categorical variable to numbers and then use stats models.Something like https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cs73mB4MFq600KI-DH0XpF154iwhAJ48?usp=sharing

Comment: Also please check sequence alignment. I think this will help you more than seasonality.  This video explains how the alignment works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBGAtxrJx0M&ab_channel=BioPandit.For alignment you can use BioPython library.